# what can I do with 2 timeseries?

Tags: time-series

In my experiminent there 1 man.

there are 5 markers on his hands. 5 on the left hand. and 5 on the right hand.
Special system is fixating position of markers (3-dim space, coordinates X, Y, Z).

Man is moving his one hand during 3 minutes. So I get first txt file (real.txt). In file 30 columns(5 markers on both hands with 3 coordinates) with numbers. 
Then he imagine that he is moving his hand(but dont move it really). I get 2nd txt file(imagine.txt)

In both files 30 columns(coordinates of markers  at each time)

I need to find some 'similarities' between this 2 series. Give me some advices what can I do with this timeseries. (for example I calculate correlation coefficient beetween real and image columns)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a data-analysis question, not a programming question.

Comment: sorry. but I dont know where to ask it. can u give me link to another community ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is much to do here.

Compute the variance of each data set, and you can tell them apart.

What else would you want to do, except distinguish them?

#### We don't have your data. Anything we say is pure speculation.

This is not an answerable question.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/213965/what-experiments-can-i-do-with-2-timeseries
Here is example of data

Comment: Idk what I want to do with it.  I just have this dataset as my course work. One of tasks was somehow find similarities between real and imaginated moves. I should do as many experiments as I want. But problem is - I dont know what to do with it

Comment: Ask your instructor?

Comment: The one thing he said
"try to find some 'similarities'. For example, calculate correlation coefficient"
But I need something more to do as I think